# Any rigorous single variable calculus books that don't cost an arm and a leg?

Tags: calculus, book-recommendation

The names that get mentioned the most are Apostol and Spivak, but they go for roughly 200$. Is there nothing in the two digits? What's wrong with these people?

Comment: You can buy Spivak used for about $50.

Comment: You can go for an ebook!

Comment: Like Ethan said, you can find used versions of Spivak for about 50-60. Get the third edition if it is cheaper (there aren't any heavy changes between the 3rd and 4th edition). I think Spivak's book is a must-read for anyone beginning to study rigorous single-variable calculus (the problems are soooo helpful for the future)

Comment: amazon.co.uk lists Spivak at £35.29 (even cheaper second hand). That must be much less than USD200 (or CAD200 or AUD200 or NZD200).

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/8126515198/ref=dp_olp_all_mbc_mma?ie=UTF8&condition=all Used copy of Apostol for about $30.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a paperback of Joe Kitchen's Calculus for $37.

> This book is on the level of the ones by spivak, courant, and apostol,
>   and is very modern, having been written in the 1960's, by a Harvard
>   instructor whose evaluation summary said; "A large minority of
>   professor Kitchen's students believe that he is God." One interesting
>   topic is a discussion of how one can do all the usual applications of
>   integrals without the integral, i.e. simply using antidifferentiation,
>   i.e. the mean value theorem. this is an outstanding book, written with
>   imagination and skill, and completely rigorous in theoretical detail.

[https://www.amazon.com/Calculus-one-variable-Joseph-Kitchen/dp/B007SZX5PM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007SZX5PM)

I think Dover is in the process of reissuing it - if so it will be reasonable. You could query them.

Comment: It's coming out in January of 2020. https://www.amazon.com/Calculus-Variable-Dover-Books-Mathematics/dp/0486838064/ref=tmm_pap_title_0?_encoding=UTF8&qid=&sr=

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Apostol price is outrageous. Still, there are plenty of moderately priced alternatives. To mention a few of the better known (all prices as per Amazon USA):

- Rudin, [*Principles of Mathematical Analysis,*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0070856133), for $31 dollars and change (I wonder about this one; it seems a bit too good);
- Courant and John, *Introduction to Calculus and Analysis, Vol. 1*, $56;
- Abbott, *Understanding Analysis*, $47;
- Thomson, Bruckner, and Bruckner, *Elementary Real Analysis*, $34, or [online](http://classicalrealanalysis.info/documents/TBB-AllChapters-Landscape.pdf) free.